# How can i vertically scroll panel in sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Below is my view , Which i am trying to scroll vertically except "betsFooter" Panel. In this view i am adding some buttons dynamically under "activeBetOptionsPanel" panel. after then dynamically added buttons are hiding behind "betsFooter" panel , I want to make it scrollable except footer.
I tried to add scrollable: true and autoScroll:true but it is not working properly.

```
Ext.define('DigitalApp.view.Bets.WagerResponse', {
extend: 'Ext.Container',
xtype: 'WagerResponse',
config: {
    id: 'wagerResponseView',
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                scrollable:true,
                autoScroll: true,
                layout: 'vbox',
                items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    id: 'wagerResponseMessage',
                    layout: 'hbox',
                    type: 'wagerBetResponse',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'label',
                            type: 'success',
                            hidden: true,
                            id: 'wagerSuccessMessage',
                            html: '<div class="wagerResponse"><div class="wagerResponseIcon"></div>Your bet has been placed <br>successfully!</div>',
                            flex: 1
                        },          
                        {
                            xtype: 'label',
                            type: 'cancel',
                            hidden: true,
                            id: 'wagerCancelMessage',
                            html: '<div class="wagerResponse"><div class="wagerResponseIcon"></div>Bet Cancelled</div>',
                            flex: 1
                        }
                    ],
                    setSuccessful: function(success) {
                        if(!success){
                            this.getInnerItems()[0].hide()
                            this.getInnerItems()[1].show()
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    id: 'betCard',
                    layout: 'vbox',
                    tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
                        '<div class="infoCard">'+
                        '<img class="betsHeader" src="resources/images/logo-drfBets.png" /><hr>' +
                        '<span id="wagerRaceDate">{raceDate:this.formatDate()}</span>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="totalCard">Total ${totalAmount}</div>',
                        {
                            formatDate: function(raceDate){
                                var date = Ext.Date.parse(raceDate, 'm-d-Y');
                                return Ext.Date.format(date, 'd F Y');
                            },

                            boxString: function(box){
                                return box ? 'Box' : '';
                            }
                        }
                    ),
                    items: [
                        {
                           xtype: 'panel',
                           type: 'cancelPanel',
                           id: 'cancelPanel'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                  xtype: 'panel',
                  type: 'activeBetOptionsPanel',
                  name: 'activeWagers',
                  title: 'betOptions',
                  layout: 'vbox',
                  cls: 'navigationBetPanel',
                  items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        type: 'viewMyBets',
                        hidden: false,
                        id: 'viewBets',
                        html: '<div>View My Bets</div>'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        cls: 'watchPanelVideo',
                        type: 'watchPanelVideo'
                    }
                  ]
                }

                ]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                type: 'betsFooter',
                cls: 'wagerFooter',
                id: 'placeWager',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        cls: 'betsLogo footerLogo'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        cls: 'wagerButton',
                        id: 'newBetButton',
                        html: "+"
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'label',
                        type: 'accountBalance',
                        id: 'accountBalance'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'label',
                        type: 'serialNo',
                        id: 'serialNo'
                    }
                ]
            }
    ]
}
```

});

Comment: try using overflowY:'auto' instead of scroll related both configs.Hope it works.Test same and reply

Comment: I am using sencha touch so auto will not work

Comment: The panel where you have given these scroll configs should have less height than that of its immediate child panel with id "wagerResponseMessage".After this case only scroll will come.

Comment: No its not working , It is scrollable but again again coming to old state.

Comment: Can you share some fiddle I will check though chrome extension.Give me some fiddle for this example

Answer (score 0):

Add height to scrollable panel.

```
 xtype: 'panel',
 height: 600,
 scrollable:{
         direction: 'vertical'
 },
 items: [
       {...
```